# Outlook 2011 crashes when connecting to Exchange server

Tags: ms-office, crash

The problem started this morning when Outlook 2011 tried to connect to the Exchange server looking for new emails. An error message came up saying that Outlook needs to close (see screenshot).

I can open Outlook and switch to *Offline Mode*, then everything is fine, but as soon as I turn off offline mode and it tries to connect to Exchange, Outlook crashes again. It works fine for other people with the same setup.

Is there anything I can do to analyze the issue? Rebuilding the identity is usually recommended in such cases, any other options?

[image: Outlook Crash]

Comment: Did you remove the account and add it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you're up-to-date with your Outlook updates.  The most recent version of Outlook is 14.3.2.

One relatively easy option would be to remove your Exchange account from Outlook, quit Outlook, quit the Database Daemon, and then launch Outlook and re-add your Exchange account.  Another option would be to create a new user account on your Mac and add your Exchange account to Outlook there.  In either case, this will tell you whether this is an issue with something on Exchange or if it's local to Outlook.

There are additional troubleshooting steps available in [this Outlook:Mac KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2405496), but the steps above are where I would start because they're the easiest.

Comment: Yes, I'm on the latest version. I ended up rebuilding the Outlook identity as described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2360509. After doing that, Outlook started without any issues.